# Unable to load Image in Drawer header

Tags: android, iphone, flutter, dart

In my flutter app I'm unable to load an image in the drawer header.
I have been at it for hours, cannot understand why it is not working.

What is wrong with it

Please help

```
Container(
  width: 100,
  height: 100,
  child: UserAccountsDrawerHeader(
    accountName: const Text(_AccountName),
    accountEmail: const Text(_AccountEmail),
    currentAccountPicture: CircleAvatar(
      backgroundColor: Colors.brown,
      child: Text(_AccountAbbr),
    ),
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
    //color: Colors.yellow,
    image: DecorationImage(
      image: AssetImage('../assets/md_drawer_header.png'),
      fit: BoxFit.cover,
      ),
    ),
  ),
),
```

Comment: What does your `pubspec.yaml` look like?

Comment: I have not changed anything to pubspec.yaml -

Comment: `dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter`

`dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter`

Comment: Did you load your assets?

Comment: How do u mean ?

Comment: Well I first like to create a directory in my project like `<app dir>/assets/images`. After that, I'll go into my `pubspec.yaml` and under `flutter:`, press tab and type `assets:`, then tab again under that and add `- assets/images/example.png`.

Comment: So I need to load images in `pubspec.yaml` like `lib/assets/images/md_drawer_header.jpg` and then use the same path in my `BoxDecoration` like - `image: AssetImage('lib/assets/images/md_drawer_header.jpg'),`

Comment: That seems like a repetitive approach

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step 1: Please remove `../` in path

code snippet

```
image: DecorationImage(
      image: AssetImage('assets/md_drawer_header.png'),
      fit: BoxFit.cover,
      ),
    ),
```

Step 2: Do not put image in `lib` folder, you can create a folder `assets` in the same level as `lib`

[image]

Step 3: In `pubspec.yaml` set

```
assets:
  - assets/
```